# Trouble with C++ Vector of Vectors

Tags: c++, file, vector

I am trying to read in a txt file line by line, where each line may have a different number of elements. I found vectors of vectors, but I can't figure out why mine is only writing to the first vector within the vector. All others are empty.

Here's the snippet of code reading in the data:

```
vector<vector<int>> all(numverts);
for (int i = 0; i <= (numverts - 1); i++) {
  // reads a line of data
  vector<int> edges;
  int connect;
  while (filein >> connect) {
    edges.push_back(connect);
  }
  all[i] = edges;
  edges.clear();
}
```

Comment: `while(filein >> connect)` will stop after the whole file has been read.

Comment: So how do I adjust to stop at each new line?

Comment: Just a general comment - it's well worth looking into using `clang-format` with your code editor. You can format the whole file with one keypress into your preferred coding style. Seriously it's probably my favourite thing about programming in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getline` and a `stringstream`. This way each line of the file is read separately, and then feed into the vector (via a stringstream).

```
vector<vector<int> > all(numverts);
for(int i = 0; i < numverts; i++)
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(filein, line);
    std::stringstream lineStream(line);
    int connect;
    while(lineStream >> connect)
    {
        all[i].push_back(connect);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't heard of stringstream. This worked perfectly. I'm glad to be learning more new things.